# Converting PDF to TIFF using Imagemagick, making portion of the page turning into black

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

While trying to convert PDF to TIF Multipage using Imagemagick, certain portion of the page turning into black.

```
Version: ImageMagick 7.1.0-0 Q16 x86_64 2021-06-13 https://imagemagick.org
Copyright: (C) 1999-2021 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: https://imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC HDRI OpenMP(3.1)
Delegates (built-in): bzlib djvu fontconfig freetype jng jpeg lzma openexr pangocairo png tiff x xml zlib
```

[Sample file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/htfe177j2rnq0wo/Sample1.pdf?dl=0)

Converted file screenshot:

[image]

Command used:

```
/usr/local/bin/magick convert -debug "Blob" -density 600X600 Sample1.pdf -type Grayscale -compress Group4 -monochrome -quality 100 -depth 1 -units PixelsPerInch -define connected-components:area-threshold=3 -define connected-components:mean-color=true -define connected-components:8 Sample1.tif
```

How can we get proper converted image?

Comment: AFAIK, all the following parts of your command are unnecessary `convert`, `-debug Blob`, `-type grayscale`, `-quality 100`, `-units PixelsPerInch`, `-define connected-components*`.

Comment: Even though if i remove them, Image is still retuning black in the linux environment.

Comment: IIRC, there was recently a bug with TIFF encoder in IM, so maybe try outputting a PNG and then (afterwards) a JPEG, just to see if it is the TIFF aspect causing problems.

Comment: my requirement is to convert the PDF to TIFF with Group4 compression, 300 DPI and black & white image. if i use a diff compression page is turning black. PNG and JPEG conversion working fine.

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me in Imagemagick 7.1.0.2 Q16 with libtiff 4.1.0. Basically, remove the alpha channel by making its background white and turning it off.

```
convert -density 300 Sample1.pdf -background white -alpha background -compress Group4 x.tiff
```

[image]